# Selenium Webdriver using java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Why is the **New** keyword not needed when instantiating the **WebElement** class but not for the **Select** class in Selenium ?
For WebElement:

```
WebElement username = driver.findElement(By.id(“Email”));
```

But for Select:

```
Select selectByValue = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id(“SelectID_One”)));
```

why the **New** keyword in Select and vice versa?

Comment: Please make sure to add all the related `tag`. That increases the chance of being answered more and sooner

Answer (score 0):

Because `WebElement` **IS NOT** a class it's an [Interface](https://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html) reside in `org.openqa.selenium`which extends `SearchContext` and `Select` is [Class](https://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/Select.html)

More info: You do not instantiate an Interface, just implementing them will have result.[this](http://www.novicehacks.info/2014/01/difference-between-classes-interfaces.html) will help you to understand

Answer (score 0):

Cause findElement method itself returns WebElement object. See definition of [By.class](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/By.html).
And WebElement is an interface so you can't instantiate it.